# Batch FOR loop echo asterisk

Tags: batch-file

I need to search multiple files within a folder in batch script and echo the not exist file and assign a variable for further logging, but unable to achieve that whenever my pattern contain (*) mark. Anyway i can achieve this?

```
SET pattern="abc*.txt" "ijk_*.txt" "xyz_*.txt"


SET count=0
FOR %%A IN (%pattern%) DO (IF EXIST "%%A" (SET /a count+=1) ELSE (
    ECHO %date% %time%: %%A file missing.
    SET fileList=!fileList! %%A
    ))
```

Comment: Your for-loop only iterates once, it uses the whole pattern as 1 argument, so it's looking for any files matching `"*abc*.txt" "%ijk_*.txt" "xyz_*.txt"`. You need to look into the `/f "tokens=..."` syntax to split the string

Comment: Could perhaps a subroutine work better? See https://gist.github.com/lassevk/33b171ccb5828257f0aed6cb0116d1dd for an untested example (untested with your if-statement, calling the func should work just fine)

Comment: ok, noted with thx.

Comment: I recommend to change the first line to `SET "pattern=abc ijk_ xyz_" ` and change third line to `FOR %%A IN (%pattern%) DO (IF EXIST "%%A*.txt" (SET /A count+=1) ELSE (`. It would be better to avoid the usage of `A` as loop variable although it is possible because of `a` and `A` can be used also as modifier on referencing the value of the loop variable. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help, especially the section about `%~aI` and other modifiers. `A` can be used as loop variable, but it's advisable to avoid `A` as loop variable.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, that's not true, the `for` loop resolves each of the patterns and loops through the all existing items matching the patterns one after another; this makes `if exist` useless...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? do you want to find out for each pattern whether or not there exists at least one matching file?

Comment: at least one matching file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trick and split `pattern` into a multi-line variable and than iterate over each line. I'm using the question mark `?` as a delimeter because it is a [reserved character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#naming-conventions) and can't be used within file names.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set patternlist="abc*.txt"?"ijk _*.txt"?"xyz_*.txt"
set pattern=!patternlist:?=^

!

SET count=0
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN (!pattern!) DO (
  if exist %%A (
    SET /a count+=1
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO %date% %time%: %%A file missing.
    SET fileList=!fileList! %%A
  )
)
```